# How to get the file path while uploading a file in jsp?

Tags: jsp

Here i facing one problem like when ever i am uploading a file in my jsp i can not able read the full file path. I am getting only the file name.Below is my code for that

```
  <td align="left">File Path  :
  <input type="file" id="biometricFile_Path" name="biometricFile_Path" /> 
  <span id="uploadsId" class="errorText" >&nbsp;
```

reading the file path like this..

```
String fileName=request.getParameter("biometricFile_Path");
```

suppose I am uploading the file having path "C:\Users\apanigrahi\Desktop\test.xls"
  but I am getting only test.xls while fetching the value through request object.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't get full path name on server side, based on security restrictions. But some versions of IE provides whole path.